# How to give exactly path in send_from_directory Flask

Tags: python, flask

As we know, the" send_from_directory" need two required parameters
1- directory
2- filename

example:

```
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\upload_foder"

filename =" report.docx"

send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
```

My question is there any way to give the send_from_directory the exact path, for example

```
exact_path = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\upload_foder\report.docx"

send_from_directory(exact_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the exact file path (aka return report.docx)

Use send_file(exactpath) instead of send_from_directory

Check the documentation here https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not possible because of the method `flask.send_from_directory(directory, path, filename=None, **kwargs)` is required two parameters one is a directory and another one is the path. In official docs from Flask suggest using `send_file` to Send a file from within a directory. ([see more](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory))

Now you can use the method `send_file` from a flask that provides the exact path with the file name. Below this the example code:

```
from flask import send_file
@app.route('/download')
def download():
    try:
        exact_path = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\upload_foder\report.docx"
        return send_file(exact_path, as_attachment=True)
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```